# create custom slash command in slack using @botname instead of /botname

Tags: slack

I tried to create a slack application using the [link](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands), its working as `/botname str`.

is there any way that we could invoke application in slack using `@botname str` instead of `/botname str`. tried searching various places, couldn't get on how to do, can anyone help on it.

Answer (score 0):

To use `@botname` instead of `\botname`, you'll need to change approach of implementation.

You need to implement by subscribing to 'Slack Events'.

**This should help you to start:**

1. https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api
2. https://api.slack.com/events/app_mention